# Help setting up mixer and headphone amp

Tags: home-studio, home

I could really use some help, I have a

- Behringer MINIMIX MIX800,
- Behringer MINIAMP AMP800,
- Audio-Technica BPHS1 Headphone Mic, running
- Windows 8.1. with a
- Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio, a
- Curtis Mathis 5.1 Surround System.and using
- Vituraldub to record

How would you set these up, cause right now my set up is not working right, the music sucks, my voice on the mic is like coming from a tin can or tunnel, or outer space.I even turn off the sound system to only get sound through my phones, makes no difference, its bot the same.

--**EDIT**--

Thank you Josh, and everyone else. first as to what I want it for. I have a You Tube channel basically for Christian music and Bible topics.

My goal is to reach out. As to my set up now. The Mix800 is wired from the out to the input on the Amp800. the input from the mixer goes to the link out on the Amp800. The link out from the Amp800 goes to the blue port on the soundcard, that is the headphone, the input from the mixer goes to line out 1 split with the front and mixer of the sound system green port.

The five ports go as to the current wiring is blue port headphones, green port front and mixer with using a split connection, nothing is in the gray port, the orange port is the center and subwoofer, the black port is the rear left and right of the sound system.

As to the mic I am using, not a cheap one, high quality, Audio- Technica BPSHS1, which is plugged into a patch cord in the mixer split to both channels to achieve left and right channel. First I am a newbe as to if Behringer is good or not, I have no idea, I was suggested to this setup, I have seen it on you tube with great sound and capabilities. I just would like to be able to do my music which is going through the mixer using music files and my voice.

So being new, I am just learning. I know the equipment I have should do what I want it to do. The Sound BlasterX-Fi Xtreme Audio is putting out great sound to the 5.1, it rocks. I just know it should be going through the mixer the same way, Yes its cheap as to my budget, however cheap don't mean junk, and before ordering the Behringer equipment I read many reviews, those were very reliable. I hope this is explains my full setup at the present, and not being real technical I do learn fast.

Again thanks to everyone.

Comment: Hi Dale.  Your question, as it stands, is a bit open ended for this site.  "How do I set this up, it's not working right," does not help anyone to help you.  How is it set up now?  What is your goal?  What other things have you tried?  Please be specific.  And welcome!

Comment: Thanks Josh, I meant to comment to you. not realizing I was not new the site, I added my set up in another comment below.

Comment: I added your comments from below into your question.  Should help new arrivals to your question have a better idea what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to mixing than gear.  Out of the box, even good sound is going to sound funny and off, even if you have everything setup correctly.  At a minimum you need to equalize a microphone to have it sound decent and you really probably want to be applying some dynamics to it as well.

The problem you are experiencing may be related to your setup or gear, particularly since some headset mics are notorious for sounding like you are in a paper bag (I am not familiar with your particular mic), but it is also highly likely to simply be an EQ problem.

Comment: Don't quite agree with this one. A good mic, in a room with good acoustics, should sound ok without any tweaking. You may still need some EQ to get the best out of it, but certainly it's a horrible idea to record with a bad frequency response because "we can fix it in post-production".

Comment: @leftaroundabout - if you are using a really good studio mic, in a clean sounding room, only doing playback in a sterile environment and are placing it properly, then maybe, but that's a lot of ifs.  They are using a headset mic, which is not going to sound super, especially if they are singing without equalization to accentuate parts of the voice that they are used to hearing.  Flat mixes, even direct to headphones, when placed close to people's mouths always sound awkward at first in my experience, at least for singing.

Comment: This isn't because the mic doesn't pick it up right, but because people's voices are naturally not flat and a mic has a very flattening impact, particularly if it is a dynamic mic close to the mouth.  Everything is captured cleanly, but you still have to space it back out.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - btw, completely off topic, but I just realized I don't think I ever commented about how much your profile picture really does scream "I'm a sound guy."  I'm not sure what it is about the look, but it does say it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If it sounds like from a tin can, tunnel, or outer space (whatever you mean by that) then there's something really wrong. It could be a lot of causes; one plausible is that you have an almost-feedback. Monitoring the mic through your surround system while recording is *of course* problematic because sound from the speakers keeps getting back in the mic. In the extreme case, that results in the well-known uncontrolled howl, but if it's just below the threshold it'll already give unpleasant resonances. If you have only the headphones on, it should be fine however.

Except of course if your recording environment sounds like a tunnel itself; often such room-acoustics problems become obvious only when using a microphone, but they're really problems of the room alone. Test the response with some clapping; if there's a "rattlesnake tail" echo then you should place some absorbers / diffusors or move to another room.

Then there's the microphone. The BPHS1 should definitely be capable of giving decent results, though like any microphone it needs a decent preamp to do so. Now, apparently you're using the AMP800 for this? Not an ideal choice I daresay, this isn't really aimed at recording. A professional preamp will have balanced XLR mic ins, for a start. **On the off-chance:** you haven't plugged the headset's 1/4" plug into the AMP800's mic input, have you? The 1/4" plug is of course for the headphones. If you're not aware of it: headphone speakers actually function as microphones, though very badly. Perhaps that's what's going on? Be sure to use the actual microphone plug. I recommend using a USB audio interface with a decent mic input (e.g. Tascam US-122), that also saves you worries about the sound card.

Finally, It's possible that you inadvertently have some weird reverb effect in your signal path. The AMP800 has an FX processor built-in – you surely have put that down – but any of the software you run might also do such stuff. A proper DAW used with ASIO drivers will give you better control than generic Windows drivers; I recommend [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/).